# Gradient texture background

Tags: iphone, ios, uikit, core-graphics

I want to create a dark grill texture that fades to black for a configuration screen under a page curl effect.

Garmin StreetPilot Onboard uses something like this:
http://www.pcmag.com/slideshow_viewer/0,3253,l%253D286397%2526a%253D286507%2526po%253D7,00.asp?p=n

How do I programmatically create a background such as this? I really don't want to include an image the size of the iPhone screen; this seems the lazy approach.

Comment: it's looks like just a gray color, isnt it?

Comment: If you look very closely at the image, especially at the bottom, you'll see it has a more subtle version of the angled grid that the iPhone had for the dock prior to iOS 4. It fades to black. I love these subtle textures; they add so much.

Comment: Personally, I would create a background like this in photoshop/pixelmator and import.  Neat to be able to say you did it programatically, but it feels a bit like a case where you'd want to use the right tool for the job and move on with life.  Time is money, as they say.

Comment: And that's probably the way I'll solve it for now, Andrew. I just want to KNOW the right way. :)

Comment: Fair enough, Steven.  Just couldn't help chiming in with a more pragmatic approach :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create it in two parts. First, draw a gradient using the normal quartz drawing functions. Then, add an overlay with a repeating pattern of dots. These dots could be a small PNG file that is tiled, or you could use quartz to draw them.

See the documentation for CGContextDrawLinearGradient and [UIColor initWithPatternImage:]

Comment: Oooh. For clarity, you're saying draw black dots on top of a gradient that will become the grid, correct? Thanks! That's exactly opposite of what I was thinking; I was busy trying to figure out how to draw the grid with a gradient on top of a black background that would become the dots.